# MatDialog - should cover specific part of the page

Tags: dialog, angular-material

I am using MatDialog and opening it from the effect. I want to cover specific part of the page. In this example, it should not cover area which is covered by border. Is it possible?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-dialog-effects-vj9qek

Comment: What do you mean by not cover it? The backdrop (grey area behind the dialog) should not cover the bordered area?

Comment: Yeah. Grey area behind the dialog should not cover the bordered area.

Answer (score 0):

We can override the modal backdrop to leave a specific space at the top... we do this by introducing a styles to our component definition.

In your [existing stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-dialog-effects-vj9qek), change **app.component.ts** to be:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';

import * as fromRoot from './reducers/';
import { OpenDialog } from './actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styles: [`
    ::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-backdrop { top: 64px; }
`]
})
export class AppComponent {
  animal: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) { 
    this.animal = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getAnimalName))
  }

  openDialog() {
    this.store.dispatch(new OpenDialog());   
  }
}
```

Comment: That will not work in all resolutions. This is just an example.

Comment: If you can share a scenario where it wouldn't work... I can try a solution and update the answer; for the scenario in your question, does this solution fail at any resolution?

Comment: It requires too much effort to create a sample code for that. Consider that, I don't want to achieve it using fixed position.